# append within loop: Skipping non-existing files

Tags: gretl

This question is related to: [Import timeseries via loop (pot. generic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931619/import-timeseries-via-loop-pot-generic)

I want to import an arbitrary number of files posited in the same directory, but not continuously labelled, e.g.: file_1,file_4,file_3001

I have a small import script that works for consecutive files similar to the following:

```
scalar first = 1 #the first file is file_1.tsv
scalar last = 5000 #the last file
base_path = "c:/results/file_"
sprintf temp_path "%s%d.tsv",base_path,first
open @temp_path --preserve
setobs 1 1 --special-time-series    
loop for (i=first+1;i<=last;i+=1) --quiet
    sprintf temp_path "%s%d",base_path,i
    append @temp_path 
endloop
```

Now, when I use it on a setting as above (with missing files) I get an error and the script stops:

> Couldn't open ...

is it possible to somehow proceed / catch the error and "continue" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "catch" command can do what you need. Take a look at the following code:

```
# Creating files
open australia.gdt
store 0.gdt PAU
store 1.gdt PUS
store 2.gdt E
store 4.gdt IAU
store 8.gdt IUS
store 10.gdt le

# Opening created files
open 0.gdt
loop i = 1..10
    catch append $i.gdt
endloop
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed... I didn't know such a command exists. Works perfect!